# Mobile view and mobile site of Sharepoint 2013

Tags: mobile

Do You know, how to turn on mobile Views in Sharepoint Sites. How to turn them on ? Do You know any tutorials how to turn on mobile in Sharepoint 2013 ?

Comment: If you would like to see your sharepoint sites in mobile view while using your PC, jus add the line to th end your URL "?mobile=1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the following  link to enable mobile view for a SharePoint site.

[Plan for mobile views in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj673030.aspx)

Mobile Browsers View is by default enable in every SharePoint site. Please check feature at **Site Settings > Manage Site Features > Mobile Browsers View.** If it is not enable than please enable it.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable mobile browser from site settings

1. Open a SharePoint site on the device.
2. In the upper right corner of the site, tap **Settings** [image], and then tap **Site settings**.
3. Under **Site Actions**, tap **Manage site features**.
4. Set the **Mobile Browser** View to **Active**. (The default setting is Active.)

To switch back to mobile view, tap **Settings** [image], and then tap **Mobile view**.